# Returning an ID Token via Googles JavaScript GSI SDK

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I'm currently integrating a frontend with a 3rd party backend that offers sign-in with social media. I'm using the Google JS SDK https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client which works fine with the one-tap login as it returns an ID Token which the backend requires. However, the downside is, if the user doesn't have a Google session, the prompt won't show.

If the user isn't logged in to Google, I've managed to prompt a login form and request a token on successful login, however, it only returns an access token. Is any way to request an ID token?

Example:

```
google.accounts.id.prompt(async notification => {
  if (notification.getNotDisplayedReason() === 'opt_out_or_no_session') {
    const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: googleClientId,
      scope: 'openid email profile',
    })

    tokenClient.callback = response => {
      // response only has access token and no ID Token
    }

    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: 'consent' })
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: googleClientId,
      callback: (user: CredentialResponse) => {
        const { credential: idToken } = user

        // I need idToken in the above requestAccessToken too
      },
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing two different namespaces in the example you have provided. The first one initializes oauth2 namespace, which starts the **authorisation** flow. This flow results in the acquisition of an access_token as you've realised.

The second one initializes the id namespace, which is responsible from the **authentication** flow. This returns an id_token, which is what you need indeed.

To keep using authentication flow beyond the capability of one-tap log in, you can render a Sign-In with Google button using the authentication initialisation. Simple initialise google.account.id.initialize() as you would. Then call one-tap prompt.

```
google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

Then in addition to that, you can render the button:

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("g-btn"), {
    type: "standard",
    logo_alignment: "left"
});
```

And

```
<div class="google-button" id="g-btn"></div>
```

Regardless of how the user decides to sign-in, it'll lead to the same callback method you've defined in the initialize() call.

Comment: Thanks, the main reason I went down my initial route was that the design had a custom Google sign-in button. I've since found that this isn't possible and we need to use the Google-hosted buttons.